# How to clean PCRE old versions

Tags: pcre

Something wrong with the PCRE6.6.6 so I was told to upgrade. After I compiled and installed PCRE8.30, the latest version. My problem still existed. Now I was told to install 8.13 version.

Actually, I found a yum source so I was about to install that. Now I can't. Yum gave me below Errors

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/man/man1/pcregrep.1.gz from install of pcre-8.13-1.jason.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pcre-6.6-6.el5_6.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/pcretest.1.gz from install of pcre-8.13-1.jason.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pcre-6.6-6.el5_6.1.i386
  file /usr/lib64/libpcre.a from install of pcre-8.13-1.jason.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pcre-devel-6.6-6.el5_6.1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.a from install of pcre-8.13-1.jason.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pcre-devel-6.6-6.el5_6.1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libpcreposix.a from install of pcre-8.13-1.jason.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package pcre-devel-6.6-6.el5_6.1.x86_64
```

Now, libpcre is all over my /lib /lib64 /usr/lib /usr/lib64.

I dare not remove/clean pcre because I heard that it would cause big problem.(yum can't be used any more)

Any idea that I can safely handle PCRE in my CentOS5.6?

Some info:

```
# pcretest -C
PCRE version 8.30 2012-02-04
Compiled with
  8-bit support only
  No UTF-8 support
  No Unicode properties support
  No just-in-time compiler support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack



# locate libpcre
/lib/libpcre.la
/lib/libpcre.so
/lib/libpcre.so.0
/lib/libpcre.so.0.0.1
/lib/libpcre.so.1
/lib/libpcre.so.1.0.0
/lib/libpcrecpp.la
/lib/libpcrecpp.so
/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0
/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/lib/libpcreposix.la
/lib/libpcreposix.so
/lib/libpcreposix.so.0
/lib/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
/lib/pkgconfig/libpcre.pc
/lib/pkgconfig/libpcrecpp.pc
/lib/pkgconfig/libpcreposix.pc
/lib64/libpcre.la
/lib64/libpcre.so
/lib64/libpcre.so.0
/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
/lib64/libpcre.so.1
/lib64/libpcre.so.1.0.0
/lib64/libpcrecpp.la
/lib64/libpcrecpp.so
/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0
/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/lib64/libpcreposix.la
/lib64/libpcreposix.so
/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0
/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcre.la
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcre.pc
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcre.pc.in
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcrecpp.la
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcrecpp.pc
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcrecpp.pc.in
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcreposix.la
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcreposix.pc
/root/software/pcre-8.20/libpcreposix.pc.in
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcre.a
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcre.la
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcre.lai
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcre.so
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcre.so.0
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcre.so.0.0.1
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcrecpp.a
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcrecpp.la
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcrecpp.lai
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcrecpp.so
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcrecpp.so.0
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0T
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcreposix.a
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcreposix.la
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcreposix.lai
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcreposix.so
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcreposix.so.0
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
/root/software/pcre-8.20/.libs/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0T
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcre.la
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcre.pc
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcre.pc.in
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcre16.pc
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcre16.pc.in
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcrecpp.la
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcrecpp.pc
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcrecpp.pc.in
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcreposix.la
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcreposix.pc
/root/software/pcre-8.30/libpcreposix.pc.in
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcre.la
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcre.lai
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcre.so
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcre.so.1
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcre.so.1.0.0
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcrecpp.la
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcrecpp.lai
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcrecpp.so
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcrecpp.so.0
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0T
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcreposix.la
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcreposix.lai
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcreposix.so
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcreposix.so.0
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
/root/software/pcre-8.30/.libs/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0T
/usr/lib/libpcre.a
/usr/lib/libpcre.so
/usr/lib/libpcrecpp.a
/usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so
/usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0
/usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libpcreposix.a
/usr/lib/libpcreposix.so
/usr/lib/libpcreposix.so.0
/usr/lib/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libpcre.pc
/usr/lib64/libpcre.a
/usr/lib64/libpcre.la
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1
/usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.a
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.la
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.a
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.la
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libpcre.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libpcrecpp.pc
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libpcreposix.pc
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.a
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.la
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.a
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.la
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.so
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.a
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.la
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.so
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpcre.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpcrecpp.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libpcreposix.pc
```

Comment: There is some improvement. pcre-6.6-6.el5_6.1.i386 should never be installed since it's not 32 system. So I yum remove this. And now I can update PCRE to a newer version 8.13. And this actually fixed all the problem that I had with my PHP problem regarding PCRE issues. But in command line. If I type pcretest -C, it's still 8.30. So I don't know how to clean up about this and why this is not over-written by 8.13. And I'm afraid that I will break things if I manually remove the binary files like pcretest